# Casting-(Base) o- What does it really do?

Tags: java, static-members

```
class Rectangle {}

class ColoredRectangle extends Rectangle {}

class Base {
    void foo(Rectangle x) {
        System.out.println("Base: foo(Rectangle)");
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    @Override
    void foo(Rectangle x) {
        System.out.println("Sub: foo(ColoredRectangle)");
    }
}

public class WhatHappensHere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub o = new Sub();
        Rectangle rc = new ColoredRectangle();

        ((Base) o).foo(rc);
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time realize if this `(Base) o` changes the static type of `o`. I remember that I was told here that it doesn't change it, so what does it do? why do I need to do that? in what conditions and for what purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not changing the static type of `o`, in that the expression `o` is still of type `Sub` - but the expression `(Base) o` is of type `Base`. What I think you may mean is that it doesn't change the type of the object that `o` refers to. In this case, there is no purpose in casting to `Base` at all. It doesn't change the execution of the `foo()` call. There are various and different cases where casting *does* make sense, however.

Comment: Like casting JonSkeet to String?

Comment: It's impossible to type-cast Jon Skeet

Comment: Even _God_ subclasses Jon Skeet.

Comment: Did you mean Mark Zuckerberg?

Comment: I hope you didn't miss http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380596/how-many-times-does-jon-skeet-appear-in-a-string

Comment: @Nir...who's Mark Zuckerberg? The name sounds familiar but I can't put a face on it.

Answer (score 1):

It does nothing. In some other language this might call the `foo` defined in `Base` but in this case it still calls `Sub.foo`